# How to change boot order to boot from USB instead of hard drive

Tags: windows-10, usb, bios

Noob question, sorry.

I am trying to install Windows 10 with a bootable USB. The only problem is I don't know how to change the boot order so that it attempts to boot from a USB drive instead of the hard drive. I have no operating system currently installed on it, what should I do? Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: There should be an option within your BIOS to change the boot order device precedence.

Comment: Could you provide some info about your desktop/laptop model?

Comment: Common keys to acces to the BIOS are: F1, F2, F10, DEL, ESC.